# How do you create a cross-reference from one Confluence page to another using REST?

Tags: macros, confluence, cross-reference, confluence-rest-api

I'm trying to publish a bunch of automatically generated pages to Confluence [using REST](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/latest-server/). The pages contain cross-references to one another, which are simple  tags for which I'm currently taking a wild guess at the URL based on the target name ("http://confluence.url/display/[space]/[name]" or something with the identifier).

There are a few disadvantages with this:

- I'm taking a guess at the URL, which involves code logic where I don't want it
- The URL that I'm guessing at may change when an addon like [Scroll Viewport](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.k15t.scroll.scroll-viewport/server/overview) is activated
- The system may not be able to differentiate between a hyperlink (page-to-external) and cross reference (page-to-page), eg. for detecting undefined or orphaned pages.

I'm looking for a way to create a proper cross reference from one page to another while creating/updating those pages via REST. I've tried:

- Regular HTML hyperlink to the page URL that I'm guessing, not desired for the reasons described above.
- Using a "[Link text|link+target]" [syntax](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AUTHGUIDE/Hyperlinks+and+Crossreferences?_sscc=t), this simply renders the square brackets to the page and does not create a reference
- [Finding a macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/macros-139387.html) to use, but it appears there is no macro for this. The Anchors macro is not what I'm looking for since that would only work for link targets within the same page.

I think I would be able to resolve all the required page ID's beforehand. Also, [macros seem to be supported by REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194918/how-do-you-insert-a-confluence-macro-into-a-page-created-by-the-confluence-rest), so a macro for cross references seems ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question:

```
<ac:link>
    <ri:page ri:content-title="TheNameOfMyPage" />
    <ac:plain-text-link-body>Link text</ac:plain-text-link-body>
</ac:link>
```

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/How-to-insert-link-to-page-in-other-space-in-user-macro/qaq-p/582753

**Update:** The ac:link macro is documented more formally here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf51/confluence-storage-format-336169254.html